# msql date comparison working ONLY if the year is is first

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-comparison

I have a that is doing a date comparison in the where clause which only works if the year is the first part of the string.  the crDate field is a DATETIME so shouldn't both of the following work?

```
and     crDate between '2009/01/01' and '2009/01/21'

and     crDate between '01/01/2009' and '01/21/2009'
```

if seems to me that both these statements are the same but the first one returns the expected result and the second one returns 0 records.

Is there a setting in mySQL that could get turned off or turned on that would make these function differently?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not smart enough to parse all possible date formats. Even people are not smart enough—is `10/01/2012` Jan 10 or Oct 1? You must perform an appropriate [conversion from string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) or rely on the default format, which is normally `YYY-MM-DD`:

```
mysql> SELECT @@date_format;
+---------------+
| @@date_format |
+---------------+
| %Y-%m-%d      |
+---------------+
```

Comment: MSSQL has never had a problem dealing with both formats so I assumed that mySql would be equally capable.  Is there a setting somewhere to tell mySql to accept either format that you are aware of.